# Determining the liklihood in Baye's rule for parameter estimation

Tags: bayesian, estimation, parameter-estimation

I have used Bayesian statistics in classes but what I am trying to do now is different than anything I have done in class.  Previously, I was given information and certain numbers adn I could calculate the the posterior value in Baye's theorem.

What I am working on now is parameter estimation.  I have a long list of values and these values can be found using an equation.  There is a term in the equation that is typically looked up on a chart that was determined from experiments.  I am trying to uses Baye's rule to estimate this term based on data instead of looking it up.  I know baye's rule is

posterior = (likelihood)(prior)/(marginal likelihood)

For my prior I have a distribution of values with the peak being on the value that I would expect from looking it up on chart. I am having trouble coming up with the likelihood.  I thought I had to fit my data to a certain distribution but I don't know how to determine what distribution to use.  How do I determine the likelihood based off my data?